# HTML Parsing Table - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to parse the second table seen below using BeautifulSoup. I am having trouble identifying the second table verses the first because the tables attributes are the exact same. How do I access the information in the table such as name = PATHWAY? What I have used so far to attempt to access the table is:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'name':'PATHWAY'})
```

I receive a response of "None" although I know the table is present. To me this means that my method to distinguish between the two is not working. Any suggestions?

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
<tr><td>

  <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td class=ue><a name="REACTION TYPE">REACTION TYPE</td><td class=ue>ORGANISM</td><td  class=ue>COMMENTARY</td><td class=ue>LITERATURE</td></tr>
<tr class=tr1>
<td class=g>condensation</td><td class=no>-</td><td class=no>-</td><td class=no>-</td></tr>
  </table>
</td></tr></table>
<br>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
<tr><td>


  <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td class=ue><a name="PATHWAY">PATHWAY</td><td class=ue>KEGG Link</td><td class=ue>MetaCyc Link</td><td class=ue></td></tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Did you get your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> soup.find(attrs={"name":"PATHWAY"})
<a name="PATHWAY">PATHWAY</a>
```

Comment: This will get the <a> elem, you'd probably want to get the table with `.findParents('table')[0]`. And that's assuming there's only one such <a> tag on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Mu Mind has it right: find the "a" then traverse back up to the parent

```
soup.find(attrs={"name":"PATHWAY"}).findParent('table')
```

That's the python way....There is a single xpath command but operating with xpath on axis is more complicated and only worth the effort it it has some specific use (xslt or javascript requirements eg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function form of `find`:

```
soup.find(lambda tag: (tag.name=='table' and \
    (tag.find('a', attrs={'name': 'PATHWAY'}) is not None)))
```